# Sql Server Query - Subquery structure for Sum of hourly record occurances between two dates

Tags: sql-server, subquery

Hard to describe in a title but here is what I'm trying to do.

I have a table called Visits containing records of people's visits to a place:

```
| Id | EntryTime | Duration | Contact_Id (Ignore this)
```

`Duration` is type double in hours.

`Entrytime` is a datetime field.

From the `EntryTime` and the `Duration` we can infer the window where the person is present.

So what I want to produce is a table which **averages the total number of people present at each hourly interval over a date period**. Just from this Visits table.

So to make it more clear imagine the dataset of 9 visits below (4 yesterday, 5 today):

```
| Id |      EntryTime      | Duration
  1    2016-05-09 09:00:00      5.5
  2    2016-05-09 10:00:00      5.5
  3    2016-05-09 11:00:00      5.5
  4    2016-05-09 12:00:00      5.5

  5    2016-05-10 09:00:00      5.5
  6    2016-05-10 10:00:00      5.5
  7    2016-05-10 11:00:00      5.5
  8    2016-05-10 11:00:00      5.5
  9    2016-05-10 12:00:00      5.5
```

Then I want to produce a result that looks like this:

```
| Hour_of_Day | Total_People
       0             0
       1             0
       2             0
       3             0
       4             0
       5             0
       6             0
       7             0
       8             0
       9             1      //because on both days one person was present at 9am.
      10             2      //because on both days two people were present at 10am.
      11             3.5    //because yesterday 1 extra came at 11, and today 2 people did.
                              This averages out at 1.5.
      12             4.5    //one more entered at 12 on both days.
      13             4.5    
      14             4.5
      15             3.5    //On both days one person left at 2:30pm.
      16             2.5    //And at 3:30pm.
      17             1      //1.5 people on average left at 4:30pm.
      18             0      //Everyone had left by 5:30pm so we have no people present 6pm (18:00) onwards.
      19             0
      20             0
      21             0
      22             0
      23             0
```

I think this is a very difficult thing to do and I'm highly lacking in experience with SQL.

My though process is to:

- Create a number sequence 0-23 as `HourOfDay`.
- Simple where statement to obtain `Visits` within a date range.
- Something like `datename(hh, EntryTime) as EntryHour` for entry.
- and `datename(hh, EntryTime) + Duration as LeavingTime` for leaving time.
- Some sort of conditional case statement where if `HourOfDay > EntryHour and HourOfDay <= LeavingTime then 1 else 0` etc. as `No_Of_People` and count these occurances.

I think this flow works but I'm struggling with piecing it together.

Let me know if I've explained it okay and if my desired result is realistic. If not maybe I should just find another way of going about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH VisitorsPerDayHour AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(date, EntryTime) AS [Day]
          ,[Hour]
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN [Hour] - DATEPART(hh, EntryTime) BETWEEN 0 AND Duration THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END), 0) AS Visitors
    FROM Visitors
         CROSS APPLY (
              VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)
                    ,(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19)
                    ,(20),(21),(22),(23)
         ) AS CA1([Hour])
    GROUP BY CONVERT(date, EntryTime)
            ,[Hour]
)
SELECT [Hour] AS Hour_of_Day
      ,AVG(Visitors) AS Total_People
FROM VisitorsPerDayHour
GROUP BY [Hour]
ORDER BY [Hour]
```

Note that this only averages over days with at least one visitor.

Answer (score 0):

First create an intermediate table to store the hours using a recursive with statement

```
with HoursOfDay as(
    SELECT 0 AS hour
    UNION ALL
    SELECT hour+1 from HoursOfDay WHERE hour < 24
),
```

Then we could allready do all computations, but it will be easier to make it in two steps. We now join both tables and figure out when the visit starts and when it finishes for each hour, since MIN and MAX don't work the way we want here, we use CASE WHEN statements:

```
Visits as(
   SELECT hour, 
        CASE WHEN peopleVisit.EntryTime < hour THEN hour 
            else peopleVisit.EntryTime end as StartTime,
        CASE WHEN peopleVisit.EntryTime + peopleVisit.Duration >hour +1 THEN hour 
            else peopleVisit.EntryTime + peopleVisit.Duration end as EndTime
   FROM peopleVisit INNER JOIN HoursOfDay WHERE peopleVisit.EntryTime < hour+1 and peopleVisit.EntryTime + peopleVisit.Duration >hour 
)
```

now we are able to get the wished result

```
SELECT hour, SUM(EndTime-StartTime) from Visits group by hour
```

I didn't test it since I don't have access to any SQL db here but this should work.

Comment: Ok I forgot to deal with DateTime but this can be done using `DATEPART(HOUR, peopleVisit.EntryTime);` and if needed going further with `minute` or even `second` then everything should be working

Comment: I get an error: Incorrect syntax near keyword "Where". I'm not sure what the issue is. Also where does the extra statement need adding?

Comment: You can just put all the code in one statement and it should work. I shoud have the time to check it later.